# Python - Convert JPG to text file

Tags: python, config

Good morning all,

I've made a Python script that adds text on top of images, based on a preset template. I'm now developing a template editor that will let the user edit the template in GUI, then save the template as a config file. The idea is that one user can create a template, export it, send it to a new user on a separate computer, who can import it into their config file. The second user will retain full edit abilities on the template (if any changes needs to be made).

Now, in addition to the text, I also want the ability to add up to two images (company logos, ect.) to the template/stills. Now, my question: Is there a way to convert a JPG to pure text data, that can be saved to a config file, and that can be reinterpreted to a JPG at the receiving system. And if not, what would be the best way to achieve this? What I'm hoping to avoid is the user having to send the image files separately.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds questionable that you want to ship an image as text file (it's easy, base64 is supplied with python, but it drastically increases the amount of bytes. I'd strongly recommend not doing that).

I'd rather take the text and embed it in the image metadata! That way, you would still have a valid image file, but if loaded with your application, that application could read the metadata, interpret it as text config.

There's EXIF and XMP metadata, for both there's python modules.

Alternatively, would make more sense to simply put images and config files into one archive file (you know .docx word documents? They do exactly that, just like .odt; java jar files? Same. Android APK files? All archive files with multiple files inside) python brings a zip module to enable you to do that easily.

Instead of an archive, you could also build a PDF file. That way, you could simply have the images embedded in the PDF, the text editable on top of it, any browser can display it, and the text stays editable. Operating on pdf files can be done in many ways, but I like Fitz from the [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/) package. Just make a document the size of your image, add the image file, put the text on top. On the reader side, find the image and text elements. It's relatively ok to do!

PDF is a very flexible format, if you need more config that just text information, you can add arbitrary text streams to the document that are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, you want to use the config file as a settings file that stores the preferences of a user, you could store such data as JSON/XML/YAML or similar, such files are used to store data in pure readable text than binary can be parsed into a Python dict object. As for storing the images, you can have the generated images uploaded to a server then use their URL when they are needed to re-download them, unless if I didn’t understand the question?